# get empty file after download

Tags: php, laravel-8, phpspreadsheet

i want to download a file of projet but i get it empty. i'am using a spreadsheet librairy
Notice : i a make a dump after save function , my file is full  and not empty in the path directory of project
Someone can help me !

bellow is my code :

```
$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load('template.xlsx');
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$filename = 'write.xls';
$worksheet->getCell('A1')->setValue('John');
$worksheet->getCell('A2')->setValue('Smith');
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xls');
$writer->save($filename);  die;
// to download file
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header("Content-Length:".filesize($filename));
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$writer->save('php://output'); 
exit();
```

i except a full file after downloading it

Comment: Your issue most likely is here: `header("Content-Length:".filesize($filename));` Since you do not write a file when downloading the result you most likely specify a file size of zero (0). Which is what you get.

Comment: when i remove die , i get the same thing  a empty file. my dump of size file is different from 0 !!

Comment: So you save to file _and_ to the output stream? It could be that the library allows for only one output. Try removing the save to file. Or, if you need the file on the server side, send the file using the `readfile` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function would work:

```
define ("ONE_DAY", 86400);
function getExisting()
{
    $rootFolder = "pathTodirectory";
    //first clear old files
    $files = scandir($rootFolder,1);
    array_pop($files); array_pop($files);
    foreach($files as $file)
    {
        $fp = $rootFolder . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file;
        $filemtime=filemtime($fp);
        if (time() - $filemtime >= (2 * ONE_DAY))unlink($fp);
    }//end clearing old files
    //second rescan folder for current files
    $files = scandir($rootFolder,1);
    array_pop($files); array_pop($files);
    $existing = array_reverse($files);
    return $existing;                
}

$existing = getExisting();
echo "\n<p> Select file or enter office number to review inventory:"; 
echo "\n    <ul>";
foreach($existing as $rpt)
{
    $spd =  "pathTodirectory" . $rpt;  \\make sure to follow up with relative path name here also
    echo "\n           <li><a href=\"$spd\" >" . $rpt ."</a></li>";
}
echo "\n    </ul>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the *load()* usage issue, your code works with following correction in my site :

```
$file_loc = 'template.xlsx';
$file_type = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($file_loc);
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($file_type);
// $spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load('template.xlsx');
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($file_loc);

$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$filename = 'write.xls';
$worksheet->getCell('A1')->setValue('John');
$worksheet->getCell('A2')->setValue('Smith');
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xls');

// save a physical file in server, you can skip this actually
$writer->save($target_dir . $filename);
// die; // don't die, be happy (^_^)

// to download file
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header("Content-Length:" . filesize($filename));
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$writer->save('php://output');
exit();
```